# Remove String and Symbols

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a query to remove some varchar and symbols from a big string, basically a table will have a column with this format(the information comes from an API call):

```
$.owner = "javier@tl.com" and $.asignee ="joe" and $.Entities.Entity = "12345" And $.CountryService.Country ="1" and $.CountryService.Service="B"
```

so the requirement is to take the main "column names" from the sample, so at the end the string will be like:

```
    owner = "javier@tl.com" and asignee ="joe" and Entity = "12345" And Country ="1" and Service="B"
```

this should be dynamic because we could have more data like  $.Entities.Name, $.CountryService.Region, etc

Comment: This sounds like a job for what ever is consuming the API, not T-SQL. Hopefully the language you are using for the application you are using to consume the API has Regex support and so can do regex replacement.

Comment: T-SQL is a poor language to do string processing in. Writing what is effectively a parser for a domain-specific language is not a task I'd put to it. Whatever is doing the API call (and I really hope that isn't being done on the SQL Server side!) should ideally also do the postprocessing of the results.

Comment: The problem seems much bigger than removing String and Symbols, a quick regex replacement  will almost do this, see: https://regex101.com/r/FqguBN/1

Comment: Could there be `$.owner.phone = "..." and $.asignee.work.phone = "..." and $.asignee.mobile.phone = "..."` which would all merge into `phone = "..."`?

Comment: no, we would have only at country or entity level, owner and asignee will be static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple and can be done leveraging `STRING_SPLIT`, `STRING_AGG`, and `CHARINDEX`.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 
  '$.owner = "javier@tl.com" and $.asignee ="joe" and $.Entities.Entity = "12345" And $.CountryService.Country ="1" and $.CountryService.Service="B"';

SELECT NewString = 
         STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(split.value,IIF(p.P1>0 AND p.P2>p.P1,p.P1+1,1),8000),'and ')
FROM        STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string,'$.',''),'and ','|'),'|')   AS split
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',split.value), CHARINDEX('"',split.value))) AS p(P1,P2);
```

**Results:**

```
owner = "javier@tl.com" and asignee ="joe" and Entity = "12345" and Country ="1" and Service="B"
```